# How can I print E number to high n precision? Using my own value

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Here is my code:

```
E = 2.7182818284590452353602875
n = int(input())
print(round(E,n))
```

For example, I need to round this to 24 decimal
But it`s gives just:

```
E = 2.71828182845  
#No more
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You can simply append remaining zeroes at the end. The actual problem is that floats are not highly precise in decimals.

Comment: You can try the "decimal" library and set prec to whatever you need.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use Python `float` for this task because it will lose numbers due to precision. Use `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
E = Decimal('2.7182818284590452353602875')
n = int(input())
print(E.quantize(Decimal('1.' + '0' * n)))
```

Output:

> 2.718281828459045235360288

Comment: You need to use `Decimal("2.7182818284590452353602875")` not `Decimal(2.7182818284590452353602875)`; if you construct a `Decimal` from `float` literal, it preserves all the precision issues of the original `float`.

Answer (score 0):

As [ingvar mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535084/364696) [the `decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is necessary to get this level of precision. That said, you can also let it do the work of generating `e` in the first place via [the `exp` recipe included in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes), so you don't have to hardcode a specific value:

```python
from decimal import localcontext, Decimal

def exp(x):
    """Return e raised to the power of x.  Result type matches input type.

    >>> print(exp(Decimal(1)))
    2.718281828459045235360287471
    >>> print(exp(Decimal(2)))
    7.389056098930650227230427461
    >>> print(exp(2.0))
    7.38905609893
    >>> print(exp(2+0j))
    (7.38905609893+0j)

    """
    with localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.prec += 2
        i, lasts, s, fact, num = 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
        while s != lasts:
            lasts = s
            i += 1
            fact *= i
            num *= x
            s += num / fact
    return +s

n = int(input())
with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = n + 1  # Use exactly the precision needed (one more than requested as 2 counts)
    print(exp(Decimal(1)))
```

which, given an input of `24`, outputs:

```python
2.718281828459045235360287
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLRjpswEHznK6bpC1wiagwEUil56hec1A9AZCN8ApvDRiFfn67hLiek6GotspjZnZHG299cY3R6v18G0@FMteqqFqrrzeDQmrpqa6MdTW6HPwsZBGe6gKY@nKLfAfhsNptXcuOgQRgqZekMZ@AaQm@uNMBcMMXAK9mxdXC3ntBVrm7IQul@XKA4mLVOpxP6QWkXeocPyzCJomimZVwkpSz9l@UHkeUyzdO9kGWRFck3AvJToIjT8iDyvTiUh1TscyFlIVORySLbPxOQsXg2@axzK94@WsNVr8eDz6Dm@6pcswo3jFBZ1G5aAvWHf@J@oBrbI@QDVTu0lXV2B65LVfOz6LHDEWLnK1nq0X5tVEuw@HFcxr7k/ZkhnrUrVHnHZAV5I7wcoVaoN2ZwWoHWT3vm1zw1c8OyHFsbBJrtfGDzu4cc1/@ieMTAqtgiAX7iryXeP1Zvb8uWMa@sMhqa6MzbFxrNK2YGYrrS7P8@knVMsLJEbUbt7PJSz1ftfpfZPw)